# Continue parsing of records if exception occurs on some record in BeanIO

Tags: java, bean-io

I am using `BeanIO` to convert flat file into list of `Object`. Using following code snippet.

```
while ((MyCustomRecord obj = (MyCustomRecord) in.read()) != null) {
         System.out.println(obj);
}
```

But problem with this is, if exception occurs during parsing of some record, It immediately stops processing records. I want to suppress such exception and want it to continue processing of next records.

Is there a way to do this?

One thing that I can try is to put `in.read` in body of `while` block and wrap it around `try/catch` but then how would I detect end condition. There seems to be no method that tells end of records.

Thanks
Jitendra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found answer in BeanIO reference documentation. I missed that earlier.

It can be done by registering your custom ErrorHandler in `BeanReader`.

```
in.setErrorHandler(new BeanReaderErrorHandlerSupport() {
            public void invalidRecord(InvalidRecordException ex) throws Exception {
                System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            } 
});
```

http://beanio.org/docs/reference/index.html#StreamValidation