# Multiple Objects parsing in single file using BeanIO

Tags: java, apache-camel, fileparsing, bean-io

I have following 2 types of records in a file, I can parse this file using BeanIO for any one of the record type 1 or 2 but I could not do both of them in a single parsor.I don't know how to use both of my mappings in single records. Please give me your guidance to do it.Thanks.

```
1   Length(20)    5       5        5      5      5
    Columns     S.No    Name    Street  City    Zip

2   Columns     S.No    Age Position        
    Length(20)    5      2   18
```

**mapping.xml**

```
<record name="employee" class="com.Employee" collection="list" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<field name="S.No" length="5" />
<field name="Name" length="5" />
<field name="Street" length="5" />
<field name="City" length="5" />
<field name="Zip" length="5" />
</record>

<record name="employee" class="com.Employee" collection="list" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<field name="S.No" length="5" />
<field name="Age" length="2" />
<field name="Position" length="12" />
</record>
```

**Update1: we can distinguish record using S.No**
There is no order of records also no dependency between records.

```
    001  Jose Str1 City 56005
    001  Hene Str1 City 66005
    005  20 General Manager  
    001  King Str1 City 76005
    005  20 General Manager  
    001  Leo  Str1 City 86005
    005  90 COO                
    005  70 Deputy Manager
```

Comment: How is the data organised in the input file? First x number of record 1 rows and then y number of record 2 rows? Also, why do you have the same record name and class for both records? Those should be different ideally.

Comment: Think about how you will identify each record?

Comment: Please find the updates, we can distinguish record using S.No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to have a class that contains a list of your `Employee` records

```
public class EmployeeGroup {

  private List<Employee> employees;
  // getter + setter
}
```

Then you need a `group` definition in your `mapping.xml` to read all the `Employee` records

```
<stream name="example" format="fixedlength">
  <group name="employeeGroup" class="com.EmployeeGroup">
    <record name="employees" class="com.Employee" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" collection="list">
      <field name="S.No" length="5" rid="true" literal="001"/>
      <field name="Name" length="5"/>
      <field name="Street" length="5"/>
      <field name="City" length="5"/>
      <field name="Zip" length="5"/>
    </record>
    <record name="employees" class="com.Employee" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" collection="list">
      <field name="S.No" length="5" rid="true" literal="005"/>
      <field name="Age" length="2"/>
      <field name="Position" length="12"/>
    </record>
  </group>
</stream>
```

Note the values for the `literal` attribute to identify the different records.

Comment: I have added one more question for this please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295712/beanio-lietral-is-coming-as-extra-line

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had Same Problem in BeanIO parser. I just use minOccurs="0" in

Do following:

don't use two  just use one  like:

```
<record name="employee" class="com.Employee" collection="list" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<field name="S.No" length="5"/>
<field name="Name" length="5" minOccurs="0"/>
<field name="Street" length="5" minOccurs="0"/>
<field name="City" length="5" minOccurs="0"/>
<field name="Zip" length="5" minOccurs="0"/>
<field name="Age" length="2" minOccurs="0"/>
<field name="Position" length="12" minOccurs="0"/>
```

if there is no record in some field, then it store default type value in POJO/Bean.

this is my example with my Drive Link Just use it:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SFSEWUVpSaAFHgYxR1PExCscimMtWpwf?usp=sharing

or use as reference:

[Continue parsing of records if exception occurs on some record in BeanIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238155/continue-parsing-of-records-if-exception-occurs-on-some-record-in-beanio)

Comment: But this will create the different format output right, my output length should be 18 always as I have given in question. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @sunleo  you can adjust length by using maxOccurs or minOccurs of records.